# Possible to get Public Transport Fare information through GoogleMapsAPI3?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I was wondering if anyone knew if this was possible, it seems to suggest from this page that the public transport trip price information is not included in the API on this page:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/

But perhaps it is in GoogleMapsAPI for Business?
Prices are sometimes available on GoogleMaps.com but they are somewhat hidden.. 
Would this just be when a 3rd party allows Google to access their feeds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having used it in the past I can tell you that for the UK (unsure on US) transport fares are not included in the business licence.

Also the business pricing scheme is a yearly subscription model and is in the thousands, don't really want to go into specific price points as they are only available on request as far as I remember. But last time I purchased on behalf of a client it was over £7k annually.

*Edit* I'm sorry to say the business licence through my experience doesn't add any functionality but allows for (virtually) unlimited map views and geocoding requests. It also allows for the use of maps on password protected pages (none public facing), so is a must for private or intranet hosted services.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ~ I read somewhere $50 a year? maybe that was for something else..

Comment: Updated answer to reflect comment, and no problem, the business documentation is not the easiest to read ever.